# Display tab characters as `^I`

Tags: shell

Command `cat` has a `-t` option

> -t      Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display tab characters as
>            `^I`.

The tab character is represented by `^I`.
I searched an explanation as:

> This is a common notation that means “Control-I” which, as it turns out, is the same as a tab character.

Apparently, there's no connections of `I` and `tab` in spelling and meaning.

How to understand it?

Comment: It comes from mapping the the ASCII value (decimal 09) of the control character to the 9th letter of the Latin alphabet (I) - see [Control character: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#History)

Answer (score 4):

> How to understand it?

By reading a manual page that has been around since Version 7 UNIX:

```
man ascii
```

See the code for the `␉` (Horizontal Tab) character.  Like most control codes, this can be typed on terminals with the chord <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.  Notice what you get if you subtract 64 from the code for the `I` character.

Observe the pattern with, say, <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and `␊` (Line Feed).  Realize, once you remember where `@` is in a U.S. keyboard layout, why <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is thus `␀`.

> I searched an explanation

Always check out the manual.  The manual, certainly on the BSDs but in cases like this one on Linux operating systems as well, is your friend.

## Further reading

- [Is CTRL+4 equal to ^4 or ^$ in caret notation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226329/)
- [cat special characters meaning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305563/)
- [How to display control characters (^C, ^D, ^[, ...) differently in the shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239808/)
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). *[ISO/IEC 9995-7 symbols for keyboard key top engravings](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/iso-9995-7-symbols.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi
- http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?++NetBSD-current
- https://man.openbsd.org/