# cat shows nothing

Tags: files, cat, file-types

My team is working on a CI environment.

A `ko` file, named `x.ko`, is always generated from the CI environment at a regular time everyday and its type is `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable`.

Today, I found that the type of this `ko` file became `data`.

I'm trying to figure out the reason.

I try to `cat` this `ko` file but the output is nothing. Then, I try to `cat -et x.ko`, and it gives me lots of `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@`...

Do you know what `^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` means?

Comment: `^@` .... that is a CTRL-@ ..... hold ctrl key and press @ ..... it is a NULL .... `0` byte

Comment: It is corrupted. Has it crashed?

Comment: You can use `od` to analyse binary data. However in this case, all the evidence suggests it is a lot of zero bytes (nulls).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your file is full of nulls, rather than empty. A regular `cat` will print the nulls to standard output, but your terminal will generally display them each as nothing, while `cat -v` represents them as `^@`. `^@` represents a null byte because the byte value of "@" (0x40, or 64) xor 64 (flip bit 7) is zero.

*Why* it's suddenly full of nulls, we can't tell from here.

This related question may be informative about the caret representation: [Are ASCII escape sequences and control characters pairings part of a standard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443484/73093)

Comment: M. Ribeiro is clearly thinking of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477537 .

Answer (score 15):

Be careful , **cat** is not the perfect tool to display data that can be binary.

A simple unix tool is **od** ( octal dump ).

A example of **od -c -tx1**

```
root@server:~# od -c -tx1 /etc/passwd | head
0000000   r   o   o   t   :   x   :   0   :   0   :   r   o   o   t   :
         72  6f  6f  74  3a  78  3a  30  3a  30  3a  72  6f  6f  74  3a
0000020   /   r   o   o   t   :   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n
         2f  72  6f  6f  74  3a  2f  62  69  6e  2f  62  61  73  68  0a
0000040   d   a   e   m   o   n   :   x   :   1   :   1   :   d   a   e
         64  61  65  6d  6f  6e  3a  78  3a  31  3a  31  3a  64  61  65
0000060   m   o   n   :   /   u   s   r   /   s   b   i   n   :   /   u
         6d  6f  6e  3a  2f  75  73  72  2f  73  62  69  6e  3a  2f  75
0000100   s   r   /   s   b   i   n   /   n   o   l   o   g   i   n  \n
         73  72  2f  73  62  69  6e  2f  6e  6f  6c  6f  67  69  6e  0a
```

so you can see that the carriage return **\n**