# Why are ctrl-m and return keys the same \r char?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, tty, keyboard-event

Anyone know why <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd> are the same control chars?

Comment: check the ASCII tables

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're asking about?

Comment: Highly related: [Are ASCII escape sequences and control characters pairings part of a standard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/443484/73093) (possible duplicate?)

Answer (score 1):

Carriage return or `/r` has ASCII/Unicode code point 13. `m` is the 13th letter of the alphabet.

Control codes go from ctrl-a (code point 1), ctrl-b (code point 2) … ctrl-z (code point 26), then Esc (code point 27), 4 more control characters, space, then the rest.

Comment: "control codes" go from from `^@` (0) to `^_` (0x1f), with `^?` (0x7f) being an outlier. They're translated from caret notation to ascii value by xor-ing them with 0x40: `#define CTRL(c) ((c) ^ 0x40)`. The space is not a control character.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> are simply "shortcuts" or alternative keys for <kbd>return</kbd>

See [The List Of Useful Bash Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.ostechnix.com/list-useful-bash-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: It's not bash's keyboard shortcuts. It's the terminal emulator's effect

Comment: Sure, I didn't write the linked website, just linked to it.